# How do I ensure an error status code for errors when returning an IQueryable from a Web API method?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi, iqueryable

I am getting started with OData through the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` package. The success cases are working, but I noticed that when an `IQueryable<T>` is successfully returned, but it fails to execute, I do not get a decent error message. Instead, I get a truncated result:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44300/odata/$metadata#Documents","value":[
```

There is nothing special in my controller:

```
public class DocumentsController : ODataController
{
    Db.Context Context { get; }

    public DocumentsController(Db.Context context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<Document>> Get()
    {
        return Context.Documents;
    }
}
```

The problem is not OData-specific: a plain `ControllerBase`-derived controller returning an `IQueryable<Document>` behaves the same way (except with a truncated result of only `[`). However, the context of OData may rule out some possible solutions.

I understand why this is happening: sending the serialised result has already started; there is no way to go back in time to un-send it and send an error response instead.

I also understand that it is not a real option to prevent in the general case: when sending many items, it's possible that all but the last would be sent without any problems and some exception could be thrown on the last item, so preventing it in the general case would require buffering the complete result.

However, it should be possible to handle at least the cases where an exception is thrown even before the `IQueryable<T>`'s returns its first result. This would cover the most severe errors where a good exception message is very helpful in debugging: database offline, database schema does not match expectations, etc.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can create a custom `IEnumerable<T>` implementation which wraps another `IEnumerable<T>`, and immediately calls `.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()` upon construction, taking care to save the enumerator and `MoveNext()` response. Then, when *my* `GetEnumerator()` is called for the first time, I return a wrapper around the saved enumerator. When its `MoveNext()` is called for the first time, I return the saved boolean. Other uses just forward to wrapped enumerable and wrapped enumerator. I will spare the code, as the implementation is almost trivial.

The tricky part is finding the right point to wrap the queryable. It needs to be after any query modifiers in the URL have been applied. There are two main options here:

1. Forget about `EnableQueryAttribute`. Instead, as Ihar Yakimush answered, I can take a `ODataQueryOptions<Document>` parameter and apply the query modifiers directly. Since I'm still in control after the query has been modified, I can then wrap it in my custom enumerable.
2. Subclass `EnableQueryAttribute` and override its `OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)` method. Then, I can check if `context.Result is ObjectResult`, and if so, if `objectResult.Value` is `IEnumerable<T>`. If both are true, then I can wrap the result.

   A variant of this approach is to put `OnResultExecuting` in a separate `ActionFilterAttribute` derivative, but it makes more sense to me to have them in the same class.

In both cases, I do have to take care of the situation where I do not get an `IQuerable<Document>`: I may get an `IQueryable<SomeWrapperAround<Document>>` instead. Handling that is easy enough. `dynamic` seemed like it would have made it exceptionally easy: just create `object Wrap(object o) => o` and `object Wrap<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable) => new EnumerableWrapper<T>(queryable)` overloads and let the runtime figure out which method to call, but unfortunately `SomeWrapperAround` can be an OData-internal class, which `dynamic` doesn't like. It's still not too difficult with manual reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [Queryable] attribute, you can invoke the query options directly in your controller. It would allow you to perform any exception handling you want and build custom response if needed.

To do so, add an ODataQueryOptions parameter to the controller method. In this case, you don't need the [Queryable] attribute. More details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#invoking-query-options-directly

Comment: I gave this a try, and it may be a part of the solution (thanks), but it doesn't help by itself. It still involves returning an `IQueryable<Document>`, and if the execution of that queryable fails, the partial response has still been sent already. Your suggestion would allow me to change the return type to `List<Document>` and return `query.ToList()`, which does handle exceptions better, but that involves loading the complete set into memory again, which is problematic for the same reason as buffering the complete result.

Comment: query results will be loaded to memory anyway, either by call ToList() or by OData handlers further.

Just in case: ToList() should be called after applying query options to ensure that you load only desired page of results (not full database)

Comment: The full query results shouldn't be loaded into memory. Each individual query result will need to be loaded into memory, sure, but not all at the same time (which `ToList()` does force). As soon as the first query result is streamed, it can be discarded. Then the second query result can be loaded, streamed and discarded, and so on. That's what happens when you do a simple `foreach (var item in query) { ... }`, and I got a strong impression that that's what happens with the default serialisation of an `IQueryable<T>` as well.

Comment: Very interesting assumption. According to it if you request 10 entries from database `foreach (var item in query)` will load them one by one to allocate memory for only 1 entry at a time ? What will be the count of requests to database in this case ?

Comment: It's a single request, and it's normal for the response to be streamed and one record to be read at a time: that's how `DbDataReader` works. Wrappers that turn it into some fancy `IQueryable<T>` and construct a `DbDataReader` on demand can preserve that behaviour, and EF does so as long as you take care not to load your entities into the data context.

Comment: So what benefit you would like to gain ? Finally all objects will be loaded in to the memory. Or idea was that garbage collector will be able to release memory for entries loaded and processed first ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the point. There's no point in holding on to all the data unless you actually still need all the data.

Comment: In general it sounds great, unfortunately applying in to this particular case very doubtful.